# how to get summary in a loop in

Tags: r

I am trying to compute summary statistics in a loop (mean, median, min, max) somehow the loop below is not running. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```r
sstat<-function(x){

Table <- tablez %>% 
           filter(Date==max(Date)) %>%
           summarise(rate_dq_re=x(rate_dq_re), 
                     rate_dq_nre=x(rate_dq_nre))
Table
}

# Summary Statistics I need to compute:
stats <- c("min","median","mean","max")

for(stats in stats) {
  sstat(stats) # THIS IS NOT WORKING- Error: couldn't find function "x"
}
```

Comment: Try `for (stat in stats)` and use just `stat` instead of `stats[stats]`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? And where is the connection between the for-loop and your definition of `Table`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Sorry I didn't post the entire code by mistake. I am updating it. I followed your earlier suggestion still it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit, but I think now it works as wanted:

```r
df <- data.frame(alpha=1:100)

sstat <- function(df, fun){
  Table <- df %>% 
    summarise(rate_dq_re=fun(alpha))
  return(Table)
}

# Summary Statistics I need to compute:
stats <- c("min","median","mean","max")

for(stat in stats) {
  df %>%
    sstat(eval(parse(text=stat))) %>%
    print()
}

# another version of your for-loop
for(stat in stats) {
  stat %>%
    parse(text=.) %>%
    eval() %>%
    sstat(df, .) %>%
    print()
}
```

Since you didn't provide any data, I just created a data.frame with some dummy values and changed your function `sstat` accordingly.

1. The function `sstat` now takes your data and a function as input and now returns the summarised table.
2. The for-loop uses `stat` as variable instead of `stats`. You can't use `stats` as variable *AND* sequence at the same time unless you really want to do something strange.
3. The function names are provided by `stats` as strings. The `eval(parse(text=.))` statement uses this strings and runs them.
4. Depending on the output you are expecting, there are several ways to remove the for-loop. Try using `*apply`-functions:

```r
sapply(stats, function(stat) sstat(df, eval(parse(text=stat))))
# or
lapply(stats, function(stat) sstat(df, eval(parse(text=stat))))
```

#### Avoiding `eval(parse(text=.))`

Instead of using `eval(parse(text=stat))` you could use `get(stat)`.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr::summarise()` one does not need to summarize in a loop. The following code takes an input data frame and column, and calculates multiple statistics on the specified column.

```
library(dplyr)

sumstats <- function(df,colName){
     df %>% summarise(minimum = min({{colName}}),
                      avg = mean({{colName}}),
                      med = median({{colName}}),
                      maximum = max({{colName}}))
}

sumstats(mtcars,mpg)
```

...and the output:

```
> sumstats(mtcars,mpg)
  minimum      avg  med maximum
1    10.4 20.09062 19.2    33.9
>
```

The original question included a step to subset the data. We can add a filter expression as an optional argument to our `sumstats()` function, check it with the `missing()` function, and conditionally subset the data. We will also calculate the number of observations used in the statistics so we can see the effect of subsetting the data on the results.

```
sumstats <- function(df,colName,aFilter=NULL) {
     if(missing(aFilter)) subset <- df
     else subset <- filter(df,{{aFilter}})
     subset %>% 
            summarise(n = n(),
                      minimum = min({{colName}}),
                      avg = mean({{colName}}),
                      med = median({{colName}}),
                      maximum = max({{colName}})) 
}
```

First, we'll generate summary statistics for `mtcars$cyl` across the entire data frame. Note that the results match the previously generated ones, with the addition of `n = 32`.

```
> sumstats(mtcars,mpg)
   n minimum      avg  med maximum
1 32    10.4 20.09062 19.2    33.9
>
```

Second, we'll run the summary statistics for cars with 4 cylinders.

```
> sumstats(mtcars,mpg,cyl == 4)
   n minimum      avg med maximum
1 11    21.4 26.66364  26    33.9
>
```

We'll verify the results by checking the mean and number of observations with a different approach.

```
> # check the mean 
> mean(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == 4])
[1] 26.66364
> # check number of obs
> nrow(mtcars[mtcars$cyl ==4,])
[1] 11
>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Len. This doesn't exactly solve what I was looking for. But this another great approach to solve the problem. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @SaurabhDatta - Thanks for the feedback, Saurabh. With large data sizes, a solution that calculates multiple statistics in a single pass of the data frame will run faster than a solution that has to loop through the same data multiple times. For example, if we build 10 million rows of random data and run it through Martin's solution and my solution, mine runs about 20% faster. For a single column it's not significant, but if you're going to summarise hundreds of columns in this manner, the improved response time becomes meaningful.

Comment: Thanks once again Len. I agree with you completely. I am currently dealing with a small dataset but in the future planning to apply to large datasets. Your solution is very useful to me too.